# Django app with logged in users

Tags: python, django, admin

I am building my first django application, I have set up a custom user and profile, I would like the users to be able to edit some of their own content and view their own pages of analytics data.

Currently my users are being created and logged in to the admin area I am using a a custom back end to allow them to see / edit the content.

My question: Should I allow my users log into the django admin area or should I build a separate login form that authenticates them and build authenticated pages, so I would end up with two admin areas the main area where I can control users and billing etc the other where the customer can view and edit profile information and interact with the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's better to create another page for the users to get control from, so you set up the authentications and all of the custom permissions that you want to give them. By giving them permissions that you set explicitly you make sure the users don't temper with anything that you don't want them to touch. So the best thing to do, is to create a custom admin panel for them. A more controlled environment for you and your users.

Answer (score 1):

The admin pages (as the name indicates) should be reserved for admins. It is designed to give access to the 'raw' data stored in the database.

For your users, you should create views, templates and forms to log in and view/change their information. This way you can choose how their info is displayed and how they are allowed to use it (validation, permissions...).